# Write an element of a group as product of generators

Tags: group-theory, computational-algebra, rubiks-cube

Say we have a finite group $G$ generated by $g_1,\cdots,g_n$. Are there any algorithms or techniques to write any element $g$ as a product of these generators?

Ofcourse we could just try all combinations, but I hope there are more elegant ways, like in a vector space, you can just project your element on the generators.

I'm asking because this is the group theoretic generalisation of solving a Rubik's cube. By labeling the stickers with natural numbers, we see that moves are permutations, and every legal position is one too. [The Rubik's cube group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group) is then the group that is generated by the legal moves:

$$G=<R,L,U,D,F,B>$$
[In standard notation](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/3x3x3_notation)

To solve the cube is the same as to write an element of this group as a product of these generators, so in this case there are [many algorithms](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/List_of_methods) to do this.

What algorithms exist for the general case?

Comment: Algorithms need inputs. How would you input an element of $G$?

Comment: for example, the disjoint cycle decomposition

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is a group of permutations of something?

Comment: every group is isomorfic to a group of permutations, also every group is isomorfic to a group of matrices, which could also be a nice input format...

Comment: You can do this efficiently if you extend the initial generating set to a strong generating set. If you then rewrite in terms of the original generators, you might end up with a very long word. Thegeneral  problem of expressing an element as a short word in the given generators is diffficult (as you can judge from the difficulty of the Rubik Cube problem). Fortunately, for may computational applications it is not necessary to do this.

Comment: There are certainly algorithms and implementations - see for example [Expressing Group Elements as Words in Generators](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7E19F92284F6684E) in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org